# Pattern matching using regex for messy file names

Tags: python, r, regex

I do not have very much experience with REs, but need to parse 100s of file names to generate a 'metadata' data set. I have been able to generate text files that include the file paths and the file name. It is simple for me to parse out the complete file name, but I need to be able to parse out the "sample ID" from the file name.

The issue is that the syntax of the "sample IDs" is all over the place (See attached csv for example data: The goal is to go from the 'sample' column to the 'ID' column). I have tried a series of strsplit() commands, but this is very cumbersome, and is not functional in nature. I have also tried writing a function with a number of IF statements based on syntax structure. I feel like this is still not a good solution because it is still dependent on me manually identifying the different syntax before hand, and I could easily miss something since I have to do this by eye.

It seems to me that this is a regex problem, but I could use some resources to help me get started. I would like to be able to do this in either R or Python if possible. Thank you for any resources, or packages/modules that may be useful.

```
dput(head(brain_ref, 25))
structure(list(file = c("/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/BXH12_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTCCGC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/BXH12_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CAGATC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB13_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ATGTCA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB13_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTGAAA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB17_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CCGTCC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB17_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ATGTCA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB2_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTCCGC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB2_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CTTGTA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB25_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTTCC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB25_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTCAA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB27_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CGATGT.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB27_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTTCC.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB7_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ACAGTG.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/HXB7_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTCAA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/SHR_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GCCAAT.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch1/ensembl_v96/SHR_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_TGACCA.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/ACI-SegHsd-2-brain-total-RNA_S17.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/BXH2-3-brain-total-RNA_S4.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/BXH5-3-brain-total-RNA_S3.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/BXH8-3-brain-total-RNA_S5.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/Cop-CrCrl-2-brain-total-RNA_S10.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/Dark-Agouti-1-brain-total-RNA_S16.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/Dark-Agouti-2-brain-total-RNA_S13.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/F344-NCI-1-brain-total-RNA_S18.genes.results", 
"/data/rn6/quantitation/brainTotalRNA/RI/batch10/ensembl_v96/F344-NCI-2-brain-total-RNA_S15.genes.results"
), sample = c("BXH12_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTCCGC", "BXH12_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CAGATC", 
"HXB13_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ATGTCA", "HXB13_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTGAAA", 
"HXB17_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CCGTCC", "HXB17_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ATGTCA", 
"HXB2_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GTCCGC", "HXB2_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CTTGTA", 
"HXB25_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTTCC", "HXB25_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTCAA", 
"HXB27_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_CGATGT", "HXB27_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTTCC", 
"HXB7_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_ACAGTG", "HXB7_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_AGTCAA", 
"SHR_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GCCAAT", "SHR_2_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_TGACCA", 
"ACI-SegHsd-2-brain-total-RNA_S17", "BXH2-3-brain-total-RNA_S4", 
"BXH5-3-brain-total-RNA_S3", "BXH8-3-brain-total-RNA_S5", "Cop-CrCrl-2-brain-total-RNA_S10", 
"Dark-Agouti-1-brain-total-RNA_S16", "Dark-Agouti-2-brain-total-RNA_S13", 
"F344-NCI-1-brain-total-RNA_S18", "F344-NCI-2-brain-total-RNA_S15"
), batch = c("batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", 
"batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", 
"batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch1", "batch10", "batch10", 
"batch10", "batch10", "batch10", "batch10", "batch10", "batch10", 
"batch10"), ID = c("BXH12_1", "BXH12_2", "HXB13_1", "HXB13_2", 
"HXB17_1", "HXB17_2", "HXB2_1", "HXB2_2", "HXB25_1", "HXB25_2", 
"HXB27_1", "HXB27_2", "HXB7_1", "HXB7_2", "SHR_1", "SHR_2", "ACI-SegHsd_2", 
"BXH2_3", "BXH5_3", "BXH8_3", "Cop-CrCrl_2", "Dark-Agouti_1", 
"Dark-Agouti_2", "F344-NCI_1", "F344-NCI_2")), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the example data with `dput` in `R` instead of image

Comment: `sub("-([0-9]+)-brain.*", "_\\1", "SHR-1-brain-total-RNA_S6")`?

Comment: @r2evans Sometimes it's underscores, not dashes.

Comment: Okay, good catch, `sub("[-_]([0-9]+)-brain.*", "_\\1", "SHR-1-brain-total-RNA_S6")`

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. (2) Even though you said there's a link (and there isn't), I suggest that links go stale, resulting in an unreproducible question. Please include sample data, as akrun suggested, using `dput` or programmatically (`data.frame` or `vec <- c("s1","s2",...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired in @r2evans [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231504/pattern-matching-using-regex-for-messy-file-names#comment106538273_60231504):

```
samples <- c("SHR_1_brain_total_RNA_cDNA_GCCAAT", "SHR-1-brain-total-RNA_S6")
sub("[_-]([0-9]+)[_-]*brain.*", "_\\1", samples)
#[1] "SHR_1" "SHR_1"
```

Comment: Thank you. This almost works, but fails in situations where the number is next to 'brain' (e.g. "F344_Stm_1braintotalRNAb30_S8_L001_R1_001")

Comment: @HarrySmith See if now with the asterisk after the second `[_-]` and before `brain` it works. `[_-]*` now means zero or more repetitions of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If all samples contain `_brain` or `-brain` and you want to keep the stuff before that you could do:

```r
names=c("ABBA-1_2-brain-total2", "BABBA-2_2_brain-total2", "ARA_1-1_2-brain-total2")
gsub("(.*).brain.*", "\\1", names)
#> [1] "ABBA-1_2"  "BABBA-2_2" "ARA_1-1_2"
```

Comment: Try `"SHR-1-brain-total-RNA-S6"`, should return `SHR_1` but is not. (See my comments from a few minutes ago.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I tried `"SHR-1-brain-total-RNA-S6"` and it does return `SHR-1`, as it should. I see no reason to downvote?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. `gsub("(.*).brain.*", "\\1", "SHR-1-brain-total-RNA-S6")` returns `"SHR-1"`, but the OP shows `"SHR_1"`. So when I said *"should return"*, I was suggesting that `"SHR-1"` is wrong.

Comment: Since the OP edited the question and changed the samples and expectations, there is no longer a string that starts with `SHR-1` and expects `SHR_1`, so I'm willing to un-downvote the question. Since SO won't let me retract a downvote unless the answer is edited, I edited your answer to (trivially) change a little so that I could retract the downvote. Feel free to rollback my edit if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, we can also remove the substring instead of capturing

```
sub("[-_]brain.*", "", names)
#[1] "ABBA-1_2"  "BABBA-2_2" "ARA_1-1_2"
```

---

Or with `trimws`

```
trimws(names, whitespace = "[-_]brain.*")
#[1] "ABBA-1_2"  "BABBA-2_2" "ARA_1-1_2"
```

---

Using the OP's example

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
brain_ref <-  brain_ref %>%
                 mutate(newsample = str_remove(sample,  "[_-]brain.*"))
```

#### data

```
names <- c("ABBA-1_2-brain-total2", "BABBA-2_2_brain-total2", "ARA_1-1_2-brain-total2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
for name in names:
    m = re.match(r'(.*)[_\-]brain[_\-]total', name)
    print(m.group(1))
```